# Listar y contar procesos linux

Tags: linux, bash

Debo hacer lo siguiente:

• Número de procesos en ejecución para el usuario actual

• Proceso más antiguo del usuario

• Listado de los procesos del usuario.

Sé que con el comando ps obtengo los procesos, pero no sé cómo asegurarme que los procesos sean obligatoriamente del usuario actual, he probado esto:

```sh
LIST_PROCESS=$(ps --no-headers | wc -l) # Añade el proceso wc al conteo, se debe eliminar.
LIST_PROCESS=$(( LIST_PROCESS - 1 )) # Se elimina el proceso sobrante.
echo "Procesos en ejecución: ${LIST_PROCESS}"
```

Eso sería para obtener el número de procesos, que no sé si hay alguna otra opción mejor.

Pero luego para obtener el proceso más antiguo, ni idea, porque en time está todo a 0.

Y no sé si los procesos que me devuelve el comando ps son los del usuario actual, porque solo son 2 y me parecen muy pocos.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Por defecto ps muestra todos los procesos con la misma id de usuario que el usuario actual. Para listar procesos de todos los usuarios, en nomenclatura BSD, se usa ps aux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te diría que así:

Número de procesos en ejecución para el usuario actual:

```
ps auz | grep <usuario> | wc -l
```

Proceso más antiguo del usuario limitado a una única linea

```
ps aux --no-headers --sort=-time |  grep <usuario> | head -n 1
```

con `--sort` puedes ordenar por lo que quieras, mira la página de `man` de `sort` y veras que tienes muchas opciones: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

Listado de los procesos del usuario.

```
ps aux
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la ayuda. Una cosa, que quizás haya entendido yo mal, pero usar "auz" o "aux" ¿no me daría todos los procesos del sistema? En ese caso, ¿no es mejor usar ps -u usuario, para que solo me dé los procesos del usuario que he puesto?

Answer (score 1):

Sacado de `man ps` (ubuntu bionic, pero no creo que cambie mucho)

```
   To see every process running as root (real & effective ID) in user format:
      ps -U root -u root u
```

O sea, `ps -U <usuario> -u <usuario> u`, y luego ya combinas con no-headers u ordenaciones. Aunque en general te recomendaria usar `pgrep` en lugar de `ps`.

Respecto al time, te sale cero porque eso es el tiempo de cpu consumido, no la fecha de arranque del proceso.